# Soon/quickly - are they interchangeable in the given context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Wanting to rid the world of himself, he jumped in front of the bus. But he did it too **quickly** and the officer was able to push him away before the bus bit him.

Wanting to rid the world of himself, he jumped in front of the bus. But he did it too **soon** and the officer was able to push him away before the bus bit him.

Are soon and quickly interchangeable here? Are both grammatically correct? Is there a difference in the overall meaning of the sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Too soon" works better. If he left it until the bus was really close (so there was no chance of being saved) that would definitely have to be "quickly", so "too quickly" doesn't work.

But I don't even like "too soon" because while reading it I thought it was going to mean "too soon to be *necessary*". So I would phrase it something like

> Wanting to rid the world of himself, he jumped in front of the bus. But **he misjudged it** and the officer was able to push him away before the bus bit him.

Comment: The bus wouldn't ***bite*** him, but it might ***hit*** him.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose; the OP used 'bit'.